# MYSQL select column as not working

Tags: mysql

Mysql:

```
SELECT `item`.*, 
       Ifnull(Group_concat(DISTINCT Concat('http://vsss.co.in/Admin/uploads/', 
              `item`.`serial`, '/', 
              item_image.image)), 'http://vsss.co.in/assets/images/No_image.png' 
       ) AS 
       Image, 
       '' 
       AS Button, 
       ( CASE 
           WHEN `user_users`.`rate_group` = a THEN `item`.`a` 
           WHEN `user_users`.`rate_group` = b THEN `item`.`b` 
           WHEN `user_users`.`rate_group` = c THEN `item`.`c` 
           WHEN `user_users`.`rate_group` = d THEN `item`.`d` 
         end ) 
       AS Price 
FROM   `items` 
       LEFT JOIN `item_image` 
              ON `item_image`.`item` = `item`.`id` 
       LEFT JOIN `cart` 
              ON `cart`.`item` = `item`.`id` 
                 AND `cart`.`user` = 3 
       LEFT JOIN `user_users` 
              ON `user_users`.`id` = 3 
GROUP  BY `item`.`id` 
ORDER  BY `item`.`id` DESC 
LIMIT  16
```

Anyone can please tell me why SELECT column as not working and How can I resolve this issue. I am new to stack community Please help me to improve question quality. Please edit the question if required.

Comment: Your question is having a mysql tag but you are talking about a vsss.php FUNCTION inexistence. Please do add the PHP code you're running and also a PHP tag to the question.

Comment: `Php (CASE WHEN `user_users`.`rate_group` = c THEN `item`.`c` end) ` php is not a mysql function

Comment: please post exact error

Comment: guys question is updated please check question detail once again.

Comment: now that you removed the PHP word from it. what are the a,b,c,d in that case statements?

Comment: @Ravi That error was removed after changes so I updated question. Please consider the updated question.

Comment: I want to select one column value from A/B/C/D as Price.

Comment: what is your problem ?

Comment: @Ravi 
I want to select one column value from A/B/C/D as Price. and that column name stored in `user_users`.`rate_group`

Comment: then you need to use single quotes around it. `rate_group = 'a'` and for the others also without it the database try either to call a function with that name or a column

Comment: you also don't need the left join on table users, you are not using it anywhere, so remove it.